# How to extract distances from delaunay triangulation to list object in R

Tags: r, delaunay

Suppose I have coordinates of points, each with ID. How sdhould I extract distances from delaunay triangulation to list object in R?

```
# My data are similar to this structure
id <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N")
x_coor <- c(0.5,1,1,1.5,2,3,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5,6,7)
y_coor <- c(5.5,3,7,6.5,5,3.5,3,1.5,1,2.5,4,5,3.5,5.5)
my.data <- data.frame(id = id, x_coor = x_coor, y_coor = y_coor)

# When I perform Delaunay triangulation, I can see the distances....
library(tripack)
my.triangles<-tri.mesh(my.data$x_coor, my.data$y_coor)
plot(my.triangles, do.points=FALSE, lwd=0.2)
points(my.data$x, my.data$y, col = "black", pch=20, cex = 1.5)
text(my.data$x, my.data$y, labels = my.data$id)
```

[image]

How can I extract "pairs" of points to list object like this?

```
# I need something like this...
my.list
[[A]]
[1] 2.55  1.58  1.41  1.58 (all distances connected to "A")
[[B]]
[1] 2.55  2.24  2.06  2.00  2.92  3.61 (all distances connected to "B")
etc.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginning at `tri.mesh()` we have:

```
my_triangles <- tri.mesh(my.data$x_coor, my.data$y_coor)
plot(my_triangles, do.points=FALSE, lwd=0.2)
```

From  `str(my_triangles)` and the R documentation on `?neighbours` we can proceed by extracting neighbours for each point as follows:

```
neiblist <- neighbours(my_triangles)
```

And then appending the point IDs from the original dataframe so that you almost have the list you want, except it contains neighbour IDs and not distances:

```
names(neiblist) <- my.data$id         #append names for later reference
```

Then compute a euclidean distance matrix with all the points:

```
euc_dist <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(x=my_triangles$x, y=my_triangles$y)))

#Append dimnames for reference

colnames(euc_dist) <- my.data$id
rownames(euc_dist) <- my.data$id
```

Find maximum neighbours a point could have: *Needed for memory preallocation*.

```
max_n <- max(unlist(lapply(neiblist, length)))
npoints <- length(my.data$id)                 # This is just the total number of points
```

Preallocate memory in which to collect results, *Important for computational efficiency and speed*:

```
dist_2neigh_mat <- matrix(nrow=npoints, ncol=max_n)    #Create results matrix

rownames(dist_2neigh_mat) <- my.data$id
colnames(dist_2neigh_mat) <- colnames(data.frame(dist=matrix(data=1:6, nrow=1)))
```

Get and collect distance vectors for all points.

```
for (i in my.data$id){
neighbors_i <- neiblist[[i]]
dist2neighbours_i <- euc_dist[,i][neighbors_i]

#Append vector with NAs to match ncol of results matrix

dist2neighbours_i <- c(dist2neighbours_i, rep(NA, 
times=(max_n-length(dist2neighbours_i))))

dist_2neigh_mat[i,] <- dist2neighbours_i   #Update results matrix with i'th distances
}
```

The `dist_2neigh_mat` contains your results. If you insist on having your results in a list exactly as stated in your question, then you just need to convert the results matrix to such a list as follows:

```
results_list <- as.list(data.frame(t(dist_2neigh_mat)))
```

You can then get rid of the NA's generated earlier for matrix integrity reasons with:

```
#Function to remove NA's

fun_NA <- function(x){x=x[!is.na(x)]
return(x)}
```

Remove NA's from results

```
results_list <- lapply(results_list, FUN=fun_NA)
```

My thinking is that this would be very very speedy even with lots and lots of points..but someone might know differently :-)

Cheers.

Comment: Great work @Shekeine! Many thanks for computational efficiency and speed particularly.

Comment: Sure, not a problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

All segments connected to 'A' have one of their endpoints equal to the coordinates of 'A'. Find those coordinates:

```
xy<- c(x-coor[id=='A'],y_coor[id=='A'])
```

If you then do, for example, `print.tri(my.triangles)` , you'll get an adjacency printout:

```
 #partial result
    triangulation nodes with neigbours:
    node: (x,y): neighbours
    1: (0.5,5.5) [4]: 2 3 4 5 
    2: (1,3) [6]: 1 5 6 7 8 9 
    3: (1,7) [3]: 1 4 14
```

By observing that the `xy` values match the first coordinate in this printout, you can grab the adjacent vertices and look up their coordinates.  It's probably easier to execute

```
my_neighbor<-neighbours(my.triangles)
# partial result:
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 5 6 7 8 9

[[3]]
[1]  1  4 14

[[4]]
[1]  1  3  5 12 14
```

Then just grab the coordinates. E.g. for the first vertex, the neighbors are 2,3,4,5.  Grab the coordinates `xtmp<- my.triangles$x[c(1,2:5)]` and `ytmp<-my.triangles$y[c(1,2:5)]` ,  build a matrix and generate the distances:

```
dist(cbind(xtmp,ytmp))
```

the first-column's results are the distances you want for your `my.list$A`

Comment: Hi @CarlWitthotf. Thank you for your answer. But data above are only a fragment from my whole dataset. I have over 1 000 points, so it will be very time demanding to extract distances for each point separately. Would it be possible to modify your answer to better fit to such situation?

Comment: @LadislavNado I'll do so if I have the time, but you should be able to take the discrete operations I presented and write some for-loops around them to automate the whole thing.